# How to invoke a web service method if it has complex type parameter/return value?

Tags: web-services

I have a problem:

I need to call a web service, using dynamic call. I let my dll generate an assembly according to the WSDL file, then using reflection to invoke the method of this assembly, the problem is the method provided by this web service has parameter/return value which is complex type not the primitive type. What should I do if I want to dynamic call this method?

For example:

This WebMethod is

```
CustomType1 Method1(CustomType2 param)

class CustomType1 { int a; int b; }

class CustomType2 { string a; string b; }
```

What I did currently is I add a CS file contains the definition of `CustomType1` and `CustomType2`, the file I wrote according to the definition in WSDL file. When program runs, it throw an exception "Type of `XXX.CustomType2` cannot be converted to type `CustomType2`"

I'm stuck, what should I do?